# SPBuiltInFieldId Conflict migrating to SharePoint 2013

Tags: migration

Our customer has a custom Content Type with the custom field *Confidential* in the SharePoint 2010 environment. Upon migration to SharePoint 2013, we discovered that Sharepoint 2013 already had that [SPBuiltInFieldId.Confidential field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.confidential(v=office.15).aspx).

Should we

1. Rename our custom field? or
2. Update our custom Content type to use the BuiltIn field Confidential?

Comment: So your static name and internal name both are same?

Comment: @Aanchal That's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rename your custom field in your environment, if that can be done without any conflict or error. There might be some issue while updating a custom field name.

Updating your content type with BuiltIn field Confidential , you will lose your data that is stored in previous fields. So you might need to copy your data from old field to new field.